# Moq Unit Test Setup Not Working

Tags: nunit, ninject, moq

I am trying to create a simple unit test using the Ninject Moq framework, and for some reason I cannot get the Setup method to work correctly. From what I understand the Setup method below should inject the repository into the Service class with the predefined result of true.

```
 [TestFixture]
public class ProfileService : ServiceTest
{
    private readonly Mock<IRepository<Profile>> _profileRepoMock;

    public ProfileService()
    {
        MockingKernel.Bind<IProfileService>().To<Data.Services.Profiles.ProfileService>();
        _profileRepoMock = MockingKernel.GetMock<IRepository<Profile>>();
    }


    [Test]
    public void CreateProfile()
    {
        var profile = new Profile()
            {
                Domain = "www.tog.us.com",
                ProfileName = "Tog",
            };

        _profileRepoMock.Setup(x => x.SaveOrUpdate(profile)).Returns(true);
        var profileService = MockingKernel.Get<IProfileService>();
        bool verify = profileService.CreateProfile(Profile);

        _profileRepoMock.Verify(repository => repository.SaveOrUpdate(profile), Times.AtLeastOnce());

        Assert.AreEqual(true, verify);
    }
}
```

When I try to verify it it I get this error:

Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: repository => repository.SaveOrUpdate(.profile)

Configured setups:
x => x.SaveOrUpdate(.profile), Times.Never

Performed invocations:
IRepository`1.SaveOrUpdate(DynamicCms.Data.DataModels.Profile)

Here is the CreateProfile Method in the ProfileService class:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Profile> _profileRepo;

        public ProfileService(IRepository<Profile> profileRepo)
        {
            _profileRepo = profileRepo;
        }
            public bool CreateProfile(ProfileViewModel profile)
        {
            Profile profileToCreate = new Profile
                {
                    Domain = profile.Domain,
                    ProfileName = profile.Name
                };

            bool verify = _profileRepo.SaveOrUpdate(profileToCreate);

            if (verify)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
}
```

**EDIT:** I replaced the Profile object being passed into

```
_profileRepoMock.Setup(x => x.SaveOrUpdate(profile)).Returns(true);
```

with

```
_profileRepoMock.Setup(x => x.SaveOrUpdate(It.IsAny<Profile>())).Returns(true);
```

This method works now, but why exactly did it not work earlier when I passed the same object into both the Verify and Setup methods.

Looking back on it, since this method is setup to return a specific value it doesn't really matter what is passed into it, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Can you post your `ProfileService.CreateProfile` method?

Comment: All set, I've just added the method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use NInject for unit test this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ProfileServiceTest : ServiceTest
{
    private readonly Mock<IRepository<Profile>> _profileRepoMock;
}
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _profileRepoMock = new Mock<IRepository<Profile>>();
}

[Test]
public void CreateProfile()
{
    var profile = new Profile()
        {
            Domain = "www.tog.us.com",
            ProfileName = "Tog",
        };

    _profileRepoMock.Setup(x => x.SaveOrUpdate(profile)).Returns(true);
    var profileService = new ProfileService(_profileRepoMock.Object);
    bool verify = profileService.CreateProfile(Profile);

    _profileRepoMock.Verify(repository => repository.SaveOrUpdate(profile), Times.AtLeastOnce());

    Assert.AreEqual(true, verify);
}
```

}

Edit: This class will have to be modified slightly

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Profile> _profileRepo;

    public ProfileService(IRepository<Profile> profileRepo)
    {
        _profileRepo = profileRepo;
    }
        public bool CreateProfile(ProfileViewModel profile)
    {

        bool verify = _profileRepo.SaveOrUpdate(profile);

        if (verify)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm actually still getting the same error message as above with this method as well.

Comment: It's because the profile object that's passed to CreateProfile is not the same passed to SaveOrUpdate. They are both of the same type, so using It.IsAny will work of course. I have updated my response to reflect a proper solution.